# css !important is not overriding style for plugin

Tags: html, css

I am showing Chargebee checkout modal in my website and I am trying to hide close button on top right.
Its class name is `cb-hp__close` and if I add CSS property `display: none` in inspect dialog of Chrome browser then it's hidden.
But when I put this CSS code in my project and refresh the page, the close button is not hidden.
I am trying like this:

```
div.cb-hp__close {
  display: none !important
}
```

It's really weird why it doesn't override CSS style.
Please let me know if somebody already encountered such case.

Comment: What is the original CSS/HTML of chargebee? Otherwise it is only guessing what happens.See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be because the plugin already has a **!important** property within its CSS code, so try to put your **!important** at the end of the execution code

Comment: Thanks for your comment Wail. It was just loading two layers and my code was applied to only one layer. That's why it seems to be no hidden.